# NPM not creating .bin directory

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm using *npm v1.4.4* and *node v0.10.25* on *Mac OS X 10.9.2*.

I've recently upgraded node and npm, and now `npm install` is no longer creating the .bin directory in node_modules.

I've deleted node_modules, tried `npm install` again, but the directory and binaries are never created.

*Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is happening?*

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "redacted",
  "author": {},
  "description": "redacted",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "*",
    "karma-coverage": "0.1.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "*",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "^0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.3.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-handlebars": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib": "^0.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `package.json`?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the package.json contents.

Comment: Quick hack: `ls node_modules | xargs -n1 npm install`

Comment: I had this problem because my disk memory was fulled

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having this issue when running calling `npm install` during a Jenkins build. The build agent is a Docker container, and `npm install` is being called inside a directory that was mounted from the host. Could any of these factors cause the silent failure of `node_modules/.bin` creation?

Comment: FWIW - i had this issue. i removed the entire node_modules directory and did `npm ci` and it started working.  not sure if either did anything, or it randomly started working.

Answer (score 28):

I know this is an old post but I experienced the same issue recently. I had copied files from an existing project including `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. The `package-lock.json` was what prevented the `node_module/.bin` directory from being created.
The solution was to delete the `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again

Comment: That did it for me! Thanks

Comment: Who knew that the `package-lock.json` would interfere with correct generation of `node_modules/.bin/`?! Well done!  My `npm install` would fail after building only 50% of `.bin` so when other run-scripts were executed the binaries would be missing.  SO ODD!  Deleted `node_modules` & `package-lock.json` and BAM it worked! Thanks!!!

Comment: Fantastic! I deleted the package-lock.json, but not node_modules. Then saw your  answer here and deleted both, and now it works! Thanks!!

Comment: After deleting `package-lock.json` then npm wouldn't even create a `node_modules` folder on `npm install` :/

Answer (score 4):

The `./node_modules/.bin` directory is where `npm` creates links to a node package's binary. From https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#executables

> ### Executables
>
> When in global mode, executables are linked into
>   {prefix}/bin on Unix, or directly into {prefix} on Windows.
>
> When in local mode, executables are linked into ./node_modules/.bin so
>   that they can be made available to scripts run through npm. (For
>   example, so that a test runner will be in the path when you run npm
>   test.)

---

The `package.json` you pasted above do not have a `bin` section. Take a look at this example from `npm`'s `package.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.4.9",
  "name": "npm",
  "publishConfig": {
    "proprietary-attribs": false
  },
  "description": "A package manager for node",
  ...
  ...
  "main": "./lib/npm.js",
  "bin": "./bin/npm-cli.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "abbrev": "~1.0.4",
    "ansi": "~0.2.1",
    ...
    ...
```

Specifically the line `"bin": "./bin/npm-cli.js"` will tell `npm` to create a link at `./node_modules/.bin/npm` to `node_modules/npm/npm-cli.js`

Comment: Presumably one of the dependencies does create `node_module/.bin` — don't grunt and karma both do that?

Comment: No `package.json` _requires_ a `bin` section. The .bin dir should still be created.

Comment: The link referenced in this answer is broken, and I don't seem to find any entry in the actual docs explaining how npm handles binaries and the `.bin` folder. This is an entry barrier for anyone who's new on this. Any ideas about where can I find proper documentation on this?

Comment: Oh, no worries, I find it: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#executables

Comment: @Auspex No, `package.json` does not require a `bin` section. Run `npm init` and install something, and you will see.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that all your dependencies are **dev** dependencies. 
Could you see if your `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `production` now? If yes you will need to change it back.

Also, any error happened during installation?

Comment: NODE_ENV is empty. 

If I move them to dependencies, or use --dev, the result it the same - no .bin directory.

No errors at all, everything looks fine.

Comment: Have you tried starting from a clean project? Also see if this helps: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2566

Comment: A fresh project behaves in the same way. That was the first link I found when trying to diagnose the problem. It didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had `webpack` running in watch mode in another console window. I did not get any errors during `npm install` so it took me a moment to notice.

1. Ensure the dependencies are not in use, such as `karma` running tests or `webpack` running in watch mode
2. Delete the dependency folders, such as `node_modules/karma`, or the entire `node_modules` folder. NPM does not seem to create symlink files in .bin folder if dependency folder already exists.
3. Retry `npm install`

With NPM 6.7.0.

Comment: Sometimes one just needs to blow away the entire `node_modules` folder to get things working...

Answer (score 2):

If all packages installed, only the `.bin` is gone.

you can just run `npm rebuild`

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but because I had a similar situation: I run npm with the `--no-bin-links` option on my VM so my windows host doesn't complain. And then later I don't find the bin links folder... duh!

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced same problem. Deleting `node_modules` and cleaning cache helped for me:

```bash
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean --force
```

Then I've installed all dependencies again.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure but maybe it doesn't create `.bin` with `NODE_ENV=production` or missing `NODE_ENV` environment variable.

Comment: If someone want to install dev dependencies with `NODE_ENV=production` you can run `npm ci --include=dev`

Answer (score -1):

This could happen because of the broken npm. Try following command from the [npm troubleshooting](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting) and it should just work fine.

```
curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```