# No .bin/ folder with NPM

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I have seen this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343420/npm-not-creating-bin-directory), but it's old, I tried everything and nothing helped me. I have a script that run just after vagrant finished to install Ubuntu 17.04. In that script I do a `sudo npm install --no-bin-links` to install the dependencies of the project cloned previously. This is the `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Just a project",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "author",
  "private": true,
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "connect-redis": "^3.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^2.8.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.4",
    "helmet": "^3.8.0",
    "marked": "^0.3.6",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "mv": "^2.1.1",
    "mysql2": "^1.4.2",
    "request": "^2.82.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.13.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "sequelize-cli": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Everything works well except the dependencies that need a `.bin` folder, like `mocha` or `sequelize-cli`. When I go to my `node_modules` of my project, there is no `.bin` folder...

Does somebody know why?

I run :
Ubuntu 17.04
Node 8.7.0
NPM 5.4.2
And everything with Vagrant and Windows 10.

Comment: Did you try running the command without the `--no-bin-links`. Something like this: `sudo npm install`

Comment: I have the symlink error, I can't use symlink if it's vagrant on top of windows :/

Comment: I hope that I'm don't offend anyone, but did you try running `ls -a` if you're using Terminal or enabling hidden folders in your file manager?

Answer (score 1):

You should install via `sudo npm install`. The `--no-bin-links` option will prevent `npm` from [adding symlinks](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) in `.bin` to the actual binaries in each installed package. AFAIK, [and according to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098812/npm-install-when-to-use-no-bin-links), this is only useful on systems without symlinks.

Comment: Without I have the symlink error... Normaly if it's [vagrant on top of windows I can't use symlink](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9901) I have to write `--no-bin-links`

Comment: Do they not work even if you run them from their own packages? Like `./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha`? @Wizix

Comment: Yes it works. I found the problem, Windows needs thé administrator rights in order to create the symlinks. I just need to run vagrant up un administrator !