How do I determine the package that installed a javascript executable?
I have file called node_modules/.bin/openapi. I was trying to figure out:

where the source is for that; and
what package created it.

I have solved the problem and I now want to know how to do this efficiently. The file node_modules/.bin/openapi is created by the @redocly/cli package. Inside the package.json it has:
"bin": {
  "openapi": "bin/cli.js",
  "redocly": "bin/cli.js"
},

The file node_modules/@redocly/cli/bin/cli.js is very simple:
#!/usr/bin/env node
  
require('../lib/index');

That's the same file that was getting installed into node_modules/.bin/openapi.
But how can you efficiently, given an install artifact like node_modules/.bin/openapi, trace back to the package that created it?

Are you sure you opened the file itself, not followed a symlink?

Please define "a javascript executable". What exactly does it look like? What created it? How can we reproduce this problem?

the question is what created it... It's a script in node_modules/.bin it magically appears when I call npm instsall. It's run with npx openapi

@Bergi I will fix the question up now

When you run npm instsall where (or with which arguments)? If you mean npm install, with no further parameters, that usually installs the current package's dependencies, so again context is everything.

I was running npm install it was installing hundreds of dependencies, I don't think matters though, assume there you ran two npm installsin sequence. The question remains is there a way to resolve the package that creates the artifact to the script that is set to run as an executable..

Also, it's not magic :-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/23536962/1048572 https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/folders#executables

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#bin - it's not relative to ./node_modules/.bin/openapi, it's relative to e.g. ./node_modules/openapi/src/cli/index.js, depending on what provides that script. You can trivially see where a symlink goes with e.g. ls.

"that's the same file that was getting installed into node_modules/.bin/openapi" - I'm pretty sure it's not the same file but rather a symlink to it

@Bergi so that's the right answer it's a symlink lol.

Depending on the environment and the availability of file manager it can take less keypresses to search for "openapi" word in package.jsons inside node_modules, the quotes can narrow down the search to "bin" entry . And fwiw the executables in .bin aren't necessary symlinks, e.g. windows

Easy answer, it's a symlink from (Bergi).
# ls -lah ./node_modules/.bin/openapi 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Oct 31 18:08 ./node_modules/.bin/openapi -> ../@redocly/cli/bin/cli.js

